# how to pass string function from command line arguments in c

Tags: c

Example  :

sum 2 3

the sum is 5

mul 2 3

the product is 6

i need to pass 3 variables from command prompt so that from the first string it should go to a function and perform the action of remaining two numbers

Answer (score 3):

This is the idea:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{ 
  if (argc != 4)
  {
    printf(" useage: %s operation num1 num2\n);", argv[0]);
    return 1;
  }

  int x = atoi(argv[2]);
  int y = atoi(argv[3]);

  if (strcmp("sum", argv[1]) == 0)
  {
    ...
  }

  ...

  return 0;
}
```